# How would I make this program two players in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could anyone help me on how to change this program so that 2 players can play it?
Define a procedure to simulate the dice throw

```
def dice(sides):
# Get a random number between 1 and 6
    throw=random.randint(1,6)
    print("score",throw)
    return throw
#Welcome messages
print("Snakes and ladders")
#Main program for the game
Player1=input("What is the name of player 1? ")
import random
position=0
#eeping it all in a loop will allow the players to keep rolling the dice until the game has finished
while position<49:
    throw=input("Roll the dice")
    dice1=dice(6)
    dice2=dice(6)
    total=dice1+dice2
#If the total of the dice thrown is not a double the player will move the total numbers of squares
    if dice1!=dice2:
        print("You are now on space", position+total)
        position=total+position
    if position>=49:
        print("You have won")
        if position<=0:
            print("You are on square 0")
#Now I will check to see if the player has rolled a double
    if dice1==dice2:
        print("This is a double you will now move back",total,"spaces")
        if position<=0:
                print("You are on space 0")
        else:
                print("You are now on space", position-total)
#This means that if the vaule of dice1 is the same as dice2 then it will move back and if not it will move forward
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could learn a lot by implementing this code using classes.

As far as keeping the code as similar as possible to the one you are using, there are many ways in which you could add a second player.

You could for example add another variable `position_p2` to store player 2's position, and repeat the same check you do for player one on player2, as follows:

```
def dice(sides): # NOTE function names should start with verbs, e.g. roll_dice
# Get a random number between 1 and 6
    throw=random.randint(1,6)
    print("score",throw)
    return throw
#Welcome messages
print("Snakes and ladders")
#Main program for the game
Player1=input("What is the name of player 1? ") #NOTE variables should be lower case

# Ask player2 for it's name
player2 = input("What is the name of player 2? ")
import random #NOTE imports should go at the beggining of the script
position_p1=0 # rename so that is easy to remember that it refers to p1
# store p2 position
positoin_p2 = 0
#eeping it all in a loop will allow the players to keep rolling the dice until the game has finished
while position<49:
    throw_p1=input("Player 1: roll the dice") #same as above
    dice1=dice(6)
    dice2=dice(6)
    total=dice1+dice2
#If the total of the dice thrown is not a double the player will move the total numbers of squares
    if dice1!=dice2:
        position_p1=total+position_p1 # you can use position_p1 += total
        print("You are now on space", position_p1)

    if position_p1>=49:
        print("Player 1 won") # Change so that you know which player has won
        if position_p1<=0:
            print("You are on square 0")
#Now I will check to see if the player has rolled a double
    if dice1==dice2:
        print("This is a double you will now move back",total,"spaces")
    position_p1 -= total
        if position_p1<=0:
                print("You are on space 0")
        else:
                print("You are now on space", position_p1)
#This means that if the vaule of dice1 is the same as dice2 then it will move back and if not it will move forward

    throw_p2=input("Player 2: roll the dice")
    dice1=dice(6)
    dice2=dice(6)
    total=dice1+dice2
#If the total of the dice thrown is not a double the player will move the total numbers of squares
    if dice1!=dice2:
        position_p2=total+position_p2 # you can use position_p1 += total
        print("You are now on space", position_p2)

    if position_p2>=49:
        print("Player 2 won") # Change so that you nkow which player has won
        if position_p2<=0:
            print("You are on square 0")
#Now I will check to see if the player has rolled a double
    if dice1==dice2:
        print("This is a double you will now move back",total,"spaces")
    position_p2 -= total
        if position_p2<=0:
                print("You are on space 0")
        else:
                print("You are now on space", position_p2)
#This means that if the vaule of dice1 is the same as dice2 then it will move back and if not it will move forward
```

This is not the best way to do this, but it should work and it is similar to the code you posted. If you want to improve the code you can try and put the parts that are the same for the 2 players in a function. You could also store player positions in a dictionary so that you can extend the game to n players. If you want to practice you can make a class for each thing in your game (the game itself, the player etc.). THen there are a bunch of other things you could do but start with some simple generalizations, like making it for n players.